# Play-Framework: import Font Awesome does not work

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, playframework-2.5

Can anybody tell me how to import Font Awesome within the Play Framework? The file containing the import statement lies in `project/app/views` and the font awesome folder lies in `project/public`. I have tried:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned(" font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")">
```

and aswell importing the relative path:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Both imports do not work. Could anybody tell me why?

EDIT:
My routes file also contains the following line:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

However, importing my main.css that lies in the same folder and is imported as follows works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a route on your route file in order to map the static files.

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET         /assets/*file                                                                                     @controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

And then link the file considering that you placed your files on `public/font-awesome-4.7.0/`:

```
<link href="@routes.Assets.versioned("font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

That's all.

More info: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview

Edit:

Your url has a space before the name of the resource and then you get a 404.

Comment: Hi pedroct92, thanks for your response. I have edited my post. My routes file already contains the mapping.

Comment: There is no error. The strange thing is that my main.css works perfectly fine. It lies in the public folder and is imported the same way <link href="@routes.Assets.versioned("....

Comment: Look the network request on the browser inspector and check the url it is requesting